# Loading LINQ results into a ViewModel that has a calculated attribute (column)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I've seen the scenarios where a ViewModel is populated with one LINQ query as shown below. **Question**: How can I populate the `TotalSale` attribute (column) - that is a grand total of Sale column - of the following ViewModel? **Note**: I'm using latest version of ASP.NET Core with VS2015.

**ViewModel:**

```
public class CategProdViewModel
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public float Sale { get; set; }
    public float TotalSale { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
var innerJoinQuery =  from category in categories
       join prod in products on category.ID equals prod.CategoryID
       select new CategProdViewModel { Category = category.Name, ProductName = prod.Name, Sale = prod.Sale };
```

Comment: Why not just settng a field value? How you expect it to be calculated? I don't see any `quantity` property here. 

P.S. how does this compile? C# doesn't have a `real` keyword. Are you using roslyn converter or something?

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy I meant `float` that gets converted to real in SQL Server during migration. I've corrected the typo after you pointed it out (thanks). No I'm not using any converter. Just simple migration to SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Okay, but you still be not answering how GrandTotal should be formed. Or you just want to duplicate one single value in all `CategProdViewModel` objects? It's possible but seems to be a mistake in logic.

Comment: @nam A grand total will be formed using a group by but you need to tell us if it will be by ProductName or by Category and ProductName or ...?

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy We are displaying the details about a selected product in a selected category as: `CategoryName, ProductName, Sale`. Let's say total product sold within a Fiscal Year were x number. Then x number of rows are displayed in a table with above mentioned columns and at the end of the sale column the grand total of that sales is displayed.

Comment: @CodingYoshi From one dropdown, user selects a category and then from another dropdown user selects a product from that selected category. Based on that selection a grand total of that sale column during the current Fiscal Year is displayed as described in my above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't clarify the structure of `Product`, but you can [Sum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734(v=vs.110).aspx) multiple values

```
var innerJoinQuery =  from category in categories
       join prod in products on category.ID equals prod.CategoryID
       select new CategProdViewModel { 
           Category = category.Name, 
           ProductName = prod.Name, 
           Sale = prod.Sale, 
           TotalSales = products.Sum(t => t.Sale) 
};
```

Without more about the code, it's hard to say, and also, the `prod.sale` is probably only going to be the amount of the last product. You can use `Sum(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, double> selector)` to sum the total of multiple items.

This is a quick answer. It will probably need to be altered depending on what the rest of your code looks like. You can also [Group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx) the query results to sum.

Comment: Your suggested solution gave me the results I needed. But - as `@CodingYoshi` eluded to in his suggested response - the `TotalSales` column is repeated (although with correct result) in each row. However in a `@foreach` statement in my View I'm not using `TotalSales` column - I'm using it only at the end for a GrandTotal. So it works. Now there may be a debatable issue on whether to use your suggested approach or the one `@CodingYoshi` provided or there may be some other possible ways of doing it. Plus, you provided your suggested solution based on the info you were given.

Comment: Yea, it definitely wasn't a complete solution. If I were doing this I would `Group` and sum them. You might want to check into doing it that way instead of the `foreach`. They both work, it's mostly preference. Glad you got it working.

Comment: I did have to use `foreach` since I am displaying a table row for `each sale` of a selected product of a selected category (from a dropdown) as explained in my comments to `@AlexZhukovskiy`.

Answer (score 2):

You will have many of these in your view:

```
public class CategProdViewModel
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public float Sale { get; set; }
    public real TotalSale { get; set; }
}
```

But you will only have the last property `TotalSale` once. Therefore, change your view model to this:

```
public class CategProdViewModel
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public float Sale { get; set; }
}
```

Create this model for your view and pass it to your view.

```
public class UseThisOnYourView // Give it another name
{
    public List<CategProdViewModel> Items { get; set; }
    public real TotalSale { get { return this.Items.Sum(x => x.Sale); } }
}
```

Then your query will be like this:

```
var innerJoinQuery =  from category in categories
       join prod in products on category.ID equals prod.CategoryID
       select new CategProdViewModel { Category = category.Name, ProductName = prod.Name, Sale = prod.Sale };

var model = new UseThisOnYourView
            { 
                Items = innerJoinQuery.ToList()
            };
```

NOTE: Please keep in mind you will need to adjust your view to use the new type you are passing to it and adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for providing another way of doing it. Your code is good in that `TotalSale` column is not repeated in the query result. And may be better performance wise (although some may argue that the `sum()` function iterates throw rows internally anyway). Your code should benefit the other readers of your response, as well.

Comment: It has to iterate to get the sum. There is no other way. But your model is cleaner now and you are not sending so much data across the wire.

Comment: I agree with you - the heavy lifting is done on server side and less data is sent across the wire. Also, I've corrected one minor typo on my ViewModel that you may want to correct as well - I meant the data type of `TotalSale` to be `float` in the ViewModel.